# "Large list context detected. Custom Views and reports may fail..." error

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, file-upload, site

A user is getting the error below:

[error http://www.acadiau.ca/~tammy/large%20list%20context%20error.png](http://www.acadiau.ca/~tammy/large%20list%20context%20error.png)

I can't find any information on the error.  List view thresholds, yes, but nothing specific to 'context'.

Thoughts? Is this concerning? i.e. poor design in that too many docs in one folder??

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is the same as "List View Threshold" - just a worded differently on a different page.